# Moving computer to new domain with same users

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller, entra-id, entra-domain-services

We currently have an Active Directory setup which was synced to our Azure AD. We are trying to migrate that to use Azure AD Directory Services which provide the domain controllers in the cloud.

I did not want to take the old domain controllers down while making the transition so I decided to go with a new domain name. The domain has changed from internal.company.com to ad.company.com.

When switching a computer from the old domain to the new one, the new user will get a new user folder on the PC. For example, a user with UPN `john.doe` now has a user folder called `john.doe.ad` when logging in with the new domain.

Would it be possible to keep the old user folder when moving to a new domain?

Also willing to accept suggestions on the best way to make this migration happen if anyone has any.

Thanks

Comment: you should have just added a new domain to an existing forest and after replication was complete used dcpromo to demote old server and again use dcpromo to promote new server to be the domain controller. this is not an answer but a regret.

Comment: @BryanCerrati This is a move to Azure AD Domain Services which is not run on a server we can control so this would not be possible.

Comment: my appologies... i didnt realize it was moving **INTO** the cloud. where are the user profiles stored? local machine or in the network?

Comment: They are on the local machines

Answer (score 1):

Two options (of many)

1 - Setup a trust and migrate the user and keep their sid...no need to muck up your permissions.

2 - Depending on the size, you could do it your way and use profwiz (3rd party software) to migrate the computer and map the old user to the new.

Comment: profwiz sounds like what I need. Will check this out tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: no problem,  like I said there are many many options, I think you'll find this to be easiest for your task and scope

Answer (score 0):

The old folders are kept, thats why you now have two folders for John Doe. Did you mean to ask for a way to have the new folder keep the same name as the old folder?
If that's what you meant, the answer is yes:

1. John Doe should logoff
2. Have another user with admin accesss to the computer rename the folder
   (john.doe.old) or delete the folder
3. John Doe can log back on to the PC with his new domain credentials